# Car will not start while trying to jump start, just clicks

Tags: electrical, battery, jeep, starter, jump-start

I have a 2012 Jeep Liberty with about 100,000 miles on it.  When I went out to it this morning to turn it on all the lights turned on for a second then went off.  After that nothing electrical in the car would turn on, not the milage indicator, no interior lights or headlights.  I took the cables for the battery off and cleaned them and reattached them, then I tried to jump start the vehicle.  While the jumper cables were hooked up, all lights in the car could turn on but whenever I tried to start it it just did a clicking noise and would never turn over.  When I disconnected the cables, none of the interior lights would turn on.  Do you think this is just a bad battery or the starter going bad?

UPDATE: It was the battery, I replaced it and now it works fine

Comment: Need to let the battery charge for a few minutes sometimes before attempting to start. Make sure there's a solid connection at both ends of the jumper cables. A 2012 Jeep is due for a new battery anyways, maybe just replace it...

Comment: I let it charge for about 5 mins before I tried to jump it.  I think the original battery is still in it

Comment: Even if you jump it, your bad battery will drop the voltage so you wouldn't be able to start it, given you battery is in very bad shape. Replace the battery.

Comment: Probably a bad ground, which was corrected when installing the new battery.